# How to fully clear Android Media Storage from different application (at least on rooted device)?

Tags: java, android, testing, mediastore

I am developing application for testing another application, in this application I am inserting/editing songs/playlists in android media storage. After many inserts/deletes app gets such error:

> SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._id (code
>   1555)
>       ...

Application is trying to remove all data (now it just removes all songs/playlists) from media storage before any insert, but seems that android saves some data in media storage (all songs/playlists are removed, seems it is some meta information with specified ID in different table), so I cannot add new song with specified ID (please do not ask why I am specifying ID of entities before inserting, it is needed for testing), only

> adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.media

helps here. I tried to call `adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.media` on rooted devices directly from application, but unfortunately it is allowed only after user approves it in dialog, but this app should work automatically, so this way does not help.

Does anybody know a way to clear media storage from application at least on rooted devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, then Tools/Android/Android Device Monitor, then click on File Explorer Tab. Could be easier.

I assume that you are aware that some app data is stored with the app in Data/Data/. This can be cleared via Settings/App//Clear Data. However, this would make it as though you have reinstalled the app, which is probably not what you want. I am pretty sure that the database would have it's data stored here by default (although I do believe that you can override this).

If you haven't you could perhaps look at some database managers Stetho for Chrome is perhaps one.

The UNIQUE constraints is saying something along the lines of. The files table has an issue when trying to add/insert a row and that is because the _id column is not unique. I think the norm is to allow the system to generate the id, perhaps the app isn't following this and is inserting with a calculated _id and it happens that the calculation method has a flaw.

Is it perhaps that deleting the underlying files has somehow caused the index number(s) to be re-used?

Comment: Hello Mike!

I cannot delete underlying files from media storage and I cannot call Setting/App/Clear Data from my application. I need to have a way to fully clear media storage via code, without any dialog prompts.
You are right, calculating method for IDs has a flaw, because of it I need a way to clear media storage **fully**, so all IDs will be valid.

Comment: What if you could remove the offending id's from the files table? That would then allow the media files to be re-added perhaps only updating the files table if they exist. Alternately amend the insert to an update which doesn't update the _id column? You could perhaps be more complex by checking the validity and or existence. along the lines of if _id = mynewid and files.filename = filename then update files.

Comment: I cannot manipulate with files, it is inner implementation of android media storage, I am working only with content provider.

Comment: That's a shame because I suspect that you may get the same issue even if you cleared the media storage as the used ID's could still exist. That is unless done by Android Media Storage itself, which I unfortunately can't help you with as you'd likely know far more than myself.